# CakePHP 2.x on CentOS 6

Tags: cakephp, centos

I am having issues with CakePHP 2.4.3 (tried on 2.5.2 too, same problem) installation on CentOS. Database can be accessed (read/write) from cakephp.

Tried for the past few hours to fix it, but here is where I am stuck :

**1) This error keeps on appearing. "URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server"**
- I have check, and the file is accessible from the site, "www.mysite.com/cake/app/webroot/css/cake.generic.css"
- I have updated httpd.conf to have "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so"
- The files ".htaccess" are in 3 folders :

/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

/app/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

/app/webroot/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

httpd.conf

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

---

**2) My controllers cannot be called directly. It needs the "index.php" to be there.**

Example :

```
Works on : "www.mysite.com/cake/index.php/grabs/myFunction"
Unable to work on : "www.mysite.com/cake/grabs/myFunction"
```

Please advise.

Comment: For ``mod_rewrite`` to be allowed to work Apache's ``AllowOverride`` directive must be set to ``All`` for cake's directory, is it?

Comment: Yes, the 'allowOverride' is there. I have added the httpd.conf part in the question above. Thx.

Comment: This may sound silly but did you restart your web server?

Answer (score 0):

An important notice for people like me, who struggled with problem exactly like this one.
One of the POSSIBLE REASON for this behavior is when there are two or more CakePHP apps residing on one server. Anyway, try changing this line:

```
// Prefix each application on the same server with a different string, to avoid Memcache and APC conflicts.
$prefix = 'myapp_';
```

From your /app/Config/core.php to something distinct, let's say:

```
$prefix = 'coolRpgGame_';
```

It really saved my life and it worked immediately.